# How to switch between pages using Playwright + dotnet 7

Tags: .net, xpath, async-await, playwright

I'm facing a problem changing windows while trying to run automated scripts using Playwright and dotnet7.

How can I perform click on the element on the new page?

```
await ClickElement(locator)
```

My code so far:

```
public class BasePage
{
    private readonly IBrowserContext _contextBrowser;
    private readonly IPage _page;
    public BasePage(Context context)
    {
        _contextBrowser = context.BrowserContext;
        _page = context.Page;
    }

    public async Task interact_tab_PromoteToProposal(string locator)
    {
        // Get page after a specific action (e.g. clicking a link)
        var newPage = await _contextBrowser.RunAndWaitForPageAsync(async () =>
        {
            await ClickElement("Transition to Promote to Proposal");
        });

        await newPage.WaitForLoadStateAsync();
        // await _page.BringToFrontAsync();
        await ClickElement(locator);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to find out what's incorrect here?

Comment: check this In Playwright there is not something called "switching to a window", you can just use a specific page or frame and it works.
Instead of using Thread.Sleep(1000); I would recommend using await Page.WaitForTimeout(1000) otherwise the events are not coming in.

What you probably want is BrowserContext.WaitForPage see here: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/next/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-wait-for-page @Bruno Lorena reftrernc https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet/issues/1953

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll consider it. 
The problem is solved, I was trying to click on the iframe, so I used FrameLocator. https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/release-notes#frame-locators

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch current page. For example:

```
var page = await CurrentContext.WaitForPageAsync();
await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync();
```

And next step, you can use your new page. For example get link.
If you need more, it's describe in documentation https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-new-pages